# Ruby -- Percent Encoding in Uploaded File

Tags: ruby, urlencode

I have encountered an issue processing a file upload in Ruby when the filename contains characters that appear to be percent encoded.

### Sample File Name: `Test %AF.txt`

### Sample Form

```html
<form id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
      action="/object/upload" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <label for="file">File:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
</form>
```

### Handle Upload

```
puts params[:file].original_filename
puts params[:file].tempfile
puts params[:file].headers
```

### Sample Output

```
Test �.jpg
#<File:0x00005618f8a3e4d8>
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Test %AF.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

### Problem Summary

params[:file].original_filename cannot be unencoded to restore the "%AF" string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem above.  The original filename is extracted from the headers attribute of the uploaded file.

```
  def uploaded_filename
    filename = params[:file].original_filename
    unless filename.valid_encoding?
      begin
        m = /filename="([^"]+)"/.match(params[:file].headers)
        filename = m[1] if m
      rescue StandardError
        filename = filename.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
      end
    end
    filename
  end
```